# How to transpose a 2D array with random length on each row?

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array

```
var arr= new List<double[]>();
```

content:

```
1   2   3
4   3   7   
7   8   9   10
11
```

I want to transpose it like a matrix to:

```
1   4   7   11
2   3   8   
3   7   9   
        10
```

then move 10 to first like :

```
1   4   7   11
2   3   8   
3   7   9   
10
```

How do I do this in a efficient way?

Comment: Efficient in what sense? Memory consumption/speed/cpu cycles?

Comment: @Caramiriel  just speed

Comment: 2 for loops, i doubt you will get this much faster

Comment: If you were to use a multi dimential array, you could use pointers and it woukd give you a performance boost as the data is stored sequentially

Comment: You don't need to transpose anything. Just change the index order when accessing your array. Was: `arr[i, j]`. Became: `arr[j, i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we have to loop through all arrays 'vertically' anyway, I seriously doubt that it can be much more efficient then nested for's

You could find a longest array and use Linq `.Where` and `.Select` with overload that accepts index:

```
var arr = new List<double[]>();
arr.Add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3});
arr.Add(new double[] { 4, 3, 7 });
arr.Add(new double[] { 7, 8, 9, 10 });
arr.Add(new double[] { 11 });

var longestArr = arr.OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).First();
var result = longestArr.Select((_, i) => arr.Where(a => a.Length > i).Select(a => a[i]).ToArray()).ToList();

foreach (var _ in result)
{
   foreach (var element in _)
   {
      Console.Write(element + " ");
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Or do the same with good old for loop:

```
var longestArrLength = arr.Max(a => a.Length);
var result2 = new List<double[]>(arr.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < longestArrLength; i++)
{
   result2.Add(arr.Where(a => a.Length > i).Select(a => a[i]).ToArray());
}
```

Output for both is:

```
1 4 7 11
2 3 8
3 7 9
10
```

Here is a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ZSKfU)